# Access ref from class component in functional component with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component in React with a ref and I want to access it within a functional component inside of it. I tried passing the ref as a prop, but then it says that it's undefined. So then I tried accessing it with `this.refs` but it's undefined too.

```
function GetOffset() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      
    console.log(this.refs);
      
  }, [offset]);
}
```

I want to use `getBoundingClientRect()` to check an offset of an element but first I need to access the ref from inside this component.

I read that using a class component would work, but I need the `useEffect()` hook. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```js
const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {
   const ref = useRef();
   const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => {
      // access ref.current
   },[offset]);
   
   return <MyClassComponent ref={ref}/>
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough!!!
I tried `useRef` before but it looks like I was doing it wrong